# List comprehension several frames

Tags: python, pandas, mutable

I will ask this question by using pd.DataFrames because the problem emerged from working with them. But it may be generalised to mutables in Python.

I want to create a list of DataFrames with one value differing.
At the moment I do:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.full((2, 2), 0), columns=['A', 'B'])
list_of_frames = []
for i in range(3):
    tmp = data.copy()
    tmp.loc[0, 'A'] = i
    list_of_frames.append(tmp)
```

I really would like to write this as a list comprehension.
For example like this:

```
[data.loc_set_copy([0, 'A'], i) for i in range(3)]
```

Since I am currently developing my own module with classes on top of pd.DataFrame, I thought about implementing this method in my own class.
My class is composed around pd.DataFrame and **does not inherit** from pd.DataFrame.

It provides wrappers for a lot of DataFrame methods and especially for `loc` and `iloc` which behave in the same way as you know from `pd.DataFrames`.

Now I have two solutions:

### Normal Method

```
def loc_set_copy(self, key, value):
    new = self.copy()
    new.loc[key[0], key[1]] = value
    return new
```

This allows:

```
[instance_of_my_class.loc_set_copy([0, 'A'], i) for i in range(3)]
```

The problem is that slices are not supported.
So if I want to change a whole columns with:

```
[instance_of_my_class.loc_set_copy([:, 'A'], i) for i in range(3)]
```

I get a Syntax Error.

### Crazy workaround

I define the following helper class:

```
class _Loc_Set_Copy():
    def __init__(self, molecule):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        new = self.data.copy()
        new.loc[key[0], key[1]] = key[2]
        return new
```

In my class definition I have:

```
 class my_class():
      def __init__(self):
          self.loc_set_copy = _Loc_Set_Copy(self)
```

Now I can use:

```
[instance_of_my_class.loc_set_copy[:, 'A', i] for i in range(3)]
```

I know that this is an abuse of syntax. Is there any other way to do this or should I just rely on the for loop in the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can pass a `slice`, use a `slice` object:

```
>>> [loc_set_copy(data, [slice(None), 'A'], i) for i in range(3)]
[   A    B
0  0  0.0
1  0  0.0,    A    B
0  1  0.0
1  1  0.0,    A    B
0  2  0.0
1  2  0.0]
```

More prettily:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([loc_set_copy(data, [slice(None), 'A'], i) for i in range(3)])
[   A    B
0  0  0.0
1  0  0.0,
    A    B
0  1  0.0
1  1  0.0,
    A    B
0  2  0.0
1  2  0.0]
>>>
```

Note:

```
>>> data.loc[:, 'A']
0    0.0
1    0.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
>>> data.loc[slice(None), 'A']
0    0.0
1    0.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Essentially, the slice notation is syntactic sugar for passing `slice` objects to `__getitem__`:

```
>>> x = list(range(22))
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
>>> x[0:10:2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> x[slice(0,10,2)]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> x.__getitem__(slice(0,10,2))
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>>
```

Note, given the above, you can simplify your method to:

```
>>> def loc_set_copy(self, key, value):
...     new = self.copy()
...     new.loc[key] = value
...     return new
...
```

If you are careful to pass `tuple`s for the `key` parameter:

```
>>> pprint([loc_set_copy(data, (0, 'A'), i) for i in range(3)])
[     A    B
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0,
      A    B
0  1.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0,
      A    B
0  2.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0]
>>> pprint([loc_set_copy(data, (slice(None), 'A'), i) for i in range(3)])
[   A    B
0  0  0.0
1  0  0.0,
    A    B
0  1  0.0
1  1  0.0,
    A    B
0  2  0.0
1  2  0.0]
>>>
```

The following should make perfect sense now:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __getitem__(self, key):
...     print(type(key))
...     print(key)
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a[1]
<class 'int'>
1
>>> a[[1]]
<class 'list'>
[1]
>>> a[object()]
<class 'object'>
<object object at 0x1003932e0>
>>>
>>> a[:1]
<class 'slice'>
slice(None, 1, None)
>>> a[:]
<class 'slice'>
slice(None, None, None)
>>> a[:,:,1:4]
<class 'tuple'>
(slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 4, None))
>>> a[:,:,[1,2]]
<class 'tuple'>
(slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), [1, 2])
>>> a[:,object():,[1,2]]
<class 'tuple'>
(slice(None, None, None), slice(<object object at 0x1003932e0>, None, None), [1, 2])
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. Although the content is not what I wanted to hear, because I like the colon notation a lot more